# How to use traits to describe operators?

Tags: scala, types, traits

I'm trying to define a trait that describes operators based on other operator. Something like this:

```
trait LessThanComparable[T] {
    def < (that: T) : Boolean

    def > (that: T) = that < this
}
```

Then I use it:

```
class Example(val x : Int) extends LessThanComparable[Example] {
    def < (that: Example) = x < that.x
}
```

But I get this: **value < is not a member of type parameter T**

How can I say that that and this are of the same Type? Or am I trying something impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
trait LessThanComparable[T <: LessThanComparable[T]] { this: T =>
  def <(that: T): Boolean

  def >(that: T) = that < this
}

class Example(val x: Int) extends LessThanComparable[Example] {
  def <(that: Example) = x < that.x
}
```

In order to be able to say `that < this`, two things must hold.

1. `that` must have a `<` method that accepts a `T`, or in other words, `that` must be a `LessThanComparable[T]`.  We can ensure this by saying that `T` must be a subclass of LessThanComparable[T], or `T <: LessThanComparable[T]`.
2. `this` must be a `T`.  We can ensure this by using a self type `this: T =>`.

So then,

```
val a = new Example(5)
val b = new Example(4)

println(a < b)  // false
println(a > b)  // true
println(b < a)  // true
println(b > a)  // false
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to follow that played out in the `Ordered` and `Ordering` traits in the standard library. The former is something like your example above. But it turns out the latter, which instead uses "type classes", is easier and more flexible.

First, define a type class and a mixin trait:

```
class Ord[T](val lessThan: (T, T) => Boolean)

trait CompareOps[T] { this: T =>
  def < (that: T)(implicit ord: Ord[T]) = ord.lessThan(this, that)
  def > (that: T)(implicit ord: Ord[T]) = ord.lessThan(that, this)
}
```

Now, for your example, all you have to do is to put an instance of your type class into implicit scope:

```
case class Example(x: Int) extends CompareOps[Example]

implicit val exampleOrd = new Ord[Example](_.x < _.x)

scala> Example(3) > Example(4)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> Example(3) < Example(4)
res1: Boolean = true
```

Normally when you're writing a class you'd put the `Ord[Example]` into `Example`'s companion object. It will then automatically be in implicit scope when an `Example` instance requires it.

Aside: you don't actually have to extend `CompareOps`, if you define `CompareOps` as a class and use an implicit conversion, but that's a bit outside the scope of this answer, so I've written it  [here](https://gist.github.com/3765066).

Comment: @Eduardo case class is just for convenience of instantiation. Try it as normal class in REPL.